# get.JSON with multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, url

I am working with get.JSON right now to fetch data from the Foursquare API (venue_history to be exact, no authorisation needed). I am able to get json data from multiple URLs. I have been told the way I have done it is not a very effective way to do so, my colleague mentioned something about putting the URLs into an array and adding a counter so it parsed each URL separately? I want to use the data from each URL to visualise it (not at that stage yet, long way to go!).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108',
    function(data){
      console.log(data);

   $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/1050511?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121109',
   function(data){
      console.log(data);

   $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/1050511?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121109',
   function(data){
      console.log(data);

   $.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/1050511?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121109',
   function(data){
      console.log(data);


          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is, how can I do this is in a more efficient way?

Thanks very much!

Here is my new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function GetJSONResult(url)
{
  $.getJSON(url,
   function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });
} 

GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It keeps on saying "unexpected identifier", I believe this is because I put all the "GetJSONResult" in the wrong place. When it was at the bottom of the code not within the function it was telling me GetJSONResult was undefined? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function

```
function GetJSONResult(url)
{
  $.getJSON(url,
  function(data){
    console.log(data);
   });
}
```

And call it using

```
GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
```

Or if you want to use an array like mentioned in your post:

```
var urls = ['https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108',
'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108',
'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108']

for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++)
{ 
    GetJSONResult(urls[i]);
}
```

In the script block you posted it would look like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("button").click(function(){
   GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
   GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
   GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
   GetJSONResult('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/venuehistory?oauth_token=2ZO1PQOUAD5SXRAJOLZVH53RBQ1EB2C23FE2GUZLJYQUJ3SY&v=20121108');
   });
});


function GetJSONResult(url)
{
   $.getJSON(url,
    function(data){
     console.log(data);
    });
}   
 </script>
```

Comment: For your second piece of code "GetJSONResult()" can I add multiple URLs, separating them with common. Thanks for your patience, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: @CharlotteSpencer No, you have to call GetJSONResult multiple times, but thats not that a big difference with adding it to an array.

Comment: Hi @Ruben-j I've added some new code as per your suggestions, but I know it's messed up, would you have any suggestions?

Comment: @CharlotteSpencer here you go. I would highly recommend you to learn the basics of jQuery, JavaScript and HTML, but thats a bit off topic.